# How to show image-based annotation view on map

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let loc = [["Title": "Banglore",
                "Latitude": 12.9716,
                "longtitute": 77.5946,
                "SubTitle": "karnataka",
                "Detial": "This is our capital"],
               ["Title": "Mumbai",
                "Latitude": 19.0760,
                "longtitute": 72.8777,
                "SubTitle": "Mahrasthra",
                "Detial": "This is our capital"],
               ["Title": "Shimla",
                "Latitude": 31.1048,
                "longtitute": 77.1734,
                "SubTitle": "Himachal",
                "Detial": "This is our capital"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for location in loc {                
            let anaomtioView = MKAnnotationView()
            let annotaion = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotaion.title = location["Title"] as? String
            annotaion.subtitle = location["SubTitle"] as? String
            anaomtioView.image = UIImage(named: "rose")
            let locations = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["Latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longtitute"] as! Double)
            annotaion.coordinate = locations
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotaion)
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your delegate methods for the map guy?

Comment: "I want to image on annotation in map"  In case you didn't know, the word 'image' is not a verb in English.

Comment: @ElTomato We don't generally use map view  delegate methods for annotation views any more. We put it in an annotation view subclass, and the register that with the map, and we're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating your `MKAnnotationView`, but never using it. But you should not instantiate annotation views yourself, anyway. Let the map view instantiate them for you as needed. All you need to do is define your own annotation view subclass, register it for your map, and you are done:

```
class RoseAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        image = UIImage(named: "rose")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And then, in `viewDidLoad`, register that annotation view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.register(RoseAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    for location in loc {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = ...
        annotation.subtitle = ...
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: ..., longitude: ...)
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Note, `viewDidLoad` isn't adding any annotation views, only registering the annotation view class with your map.

That yields:

[image]

---

Note, in old iOS versions, or in situations where you have more complicated combinations of annotation views, you can set the `delegate` for your map view and then implement your own [`mapView(_:viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview), but that is generally not needed for simple scenarios.